# Nothing happens after startActivity in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a very weird problems about android "startActivity()" method. The new Activity is not started after I called "startActivity()" method.

This is my code :

```js
val ini = this
adapter.setOnDetailListener(object : DetailListener {
    override fun onDetail(key: String) {
        val destination = Intent(ini, DetailKontrakanActivity::class.java)

        Log.e("ANAK_KOST","onDetailKontrakan")


        destination.putExtra("KEY",key)

        ini.startActivity(destination)
    }
})
```

This is my log :

```js
2018-09-27 14:12:38.621 478-2366/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
2018-09-27 14:12:38.770 17514-17514/? E/ANAK_KOST: goToDetailKontrakan
2018-09-27 14:12:38.771 17514-17514/? E/ANAK_KOST: onDetailKontrakan
2018-09-27 14:12:38.771 17514-17514/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:63333082
2018-09-27 14:12:38.776 1546-2979/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=galihlprakoso.com.anakkostv3/.View.ReusableActivities.DetailKostActivity (has extras)} from uid 10391 on display 0
2018-09-27 14:12:38.784 1546-2979/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
2018-09-27 14:12:38.789 17514-17514/? I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event listener
2018-09-27 14:12:38.796 2703-2819/? I/WtProcessController: MOVE TO FOREGROUND: galihlprakoso.com.anakkostv3 10391
2018-09-27 14:12:38.796 2703-2819/? I/WtProcessController: FOREGROUND INFO: name=galihlprakoso.com.anakkostv3 uid=10391 pid=17514 TaskId:265
2018-09-27 14:12:38.797 1546-2979/? I/Timeline: Timeline: App_transition_ready time:63333108
```

The Log "onDetailKontrakan" is printed on Log but The startActivity() method is not calling the new Activity.

I used that code on some Fragments it works, but not work in activity.

This is my whole Adapter Class Code :

```js
class DataKostAdapter(var listKost: ArrayList<Kost>, private val activity: Context,private val tipe:Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DataKostAdapter.DataKostViewHolder>() {

    companion object {

        val CRUD = 0
        val NO_CRUD = 1

    }

    private var hapusListener:HapusListener? = null
    private var detailListener:DetailListener? = null
    private var backupListKost:ArrayList<Kost> = ArrayList()


    init{
        listKost.forEach { kost ->
            backupListKost.add(kost)
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataKostViewHolder {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemRvDataKostBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                        R.layout.item_rv_data_kost,parent,false)


        return DataKostViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataKostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val kost = listKost[position]

        holder.binding.kost = kost
        holder.binding.adapter = this

        if (kost.gambar.length != 0) {
            Glide.with(activity).load(kost.gambar).into(holder.binding.itemRvDataKostImg)
        }

        holder.binding.itemRvDataKostWrapper
                .setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener{
                    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                        goToDetailKost(kost)
                    }
                })

        if(tipe == NO_CRUD){
            holder.binding.itemRvDataKostEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.binding.itemRvDataKostHapus.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listKost.size
    }

    fun goToEditKost(kost: Kost) {
        val intent = Intent(activity, FormKostActivity::class.java)

        intent.putExtra(FormKostActivity.TIPE_FORM,FormKostActivity.EDIT)
        intent.putExtra("KEY",kost.key)

        activity.startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun setOnHapusListener(hapusListener: HapusListener){
        this.hapusListener = hapusListener
    }

    fun setOnDetailListener(detailListener: DetailListener){
        this.detailListener = detailListener
    }

    fun hapusKost(kost: Kost){
        if(hapusListener!=null){
            hapusListener!!.onHapus(kost.key)
        }
    }

    fun goToDetailKost(kost: Kost) {

        Log.e("ANAK_KOST","goToDetailKost")

        if(detailListener!=null){
            detailListener!!.onDetail(kost.key)
        }
    }

    fun search(query:String){

        listKost.clear()

        if(query == "" || query.isEmpty()){

            backupListKost.forEach { kost ->
                listKost.add(kost)
            }

        }else{

            backupListKost.forEach { kost ->

                if(kost.nama.contains(query, ignoreCase = true)){

                    listKost.add(kost)
                }

            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    fun sortByHargaSewa(){

        val temp = ArrayList<Kost>()

        val length = listKost.size

        Log.e("ANAK_KOST","Length :"+length)

        if(length>1){
            while(true){

                var chosen = 0

                for(i in 0..listKost.size-1){

                    val kost = listKost.get(i)
                    val termurah = listKost.get(chosen)

                    if(kost.harga_sewa <= termurah.harga_sewa){
                        chosen = i
                    }

                }

                temp.add(listKost.get(chosen))
                listKost.removeAt(chosen)


                if(temp.size == length){
                    break
                }
            }

            listKost = temp
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    }

    fun sortByRating(){

        val temp = ArrayList<Kost>()

        val length = listKost.size

        if(length>1){
            while(true){

                var chosen = 0

                for(i in 0..listKost.size-1){

                    val kost = listKost.get(i)
                    val terpopuler = listKost.get(chosen)

                    if(kost.rating <= terpopuler.rating){
                        chosen = i
                    }

                }

                temp.add(listKost.get(chosen))
                listKost.removeAt(chosen)

                if(temp.size==length){
                    break
                }

            }

            listKost = temp
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }





    inner class DataKostViewHolder(internal var binding: ItemRvDataKostBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

Comment: check the context passing to Intent.

Comment: I used that code on some Fragments it works, but not work on that activity.

Comment: Do you set view pool for recyclerview?

Comment: sure. the listener works proven by the Log.

Comment: I faced this problem before, but I don't remember how it solved. I'm thinking.

Comment: okay. I'm waiting.

Comment: can you mention whole adapter

Comment: I've already updated my question by mention the whole adapter. @AbhinavGupta

Comment: A common issue is that the activity is immediately finished after being started.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!!!!! Very much @DanielZolnai . Issue Closed!

Comment: I submitted my comment as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common issue is that the activity is immediately finished after being started, so you won't see it appearing.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be that the callback is not invoked on the UI thread. 
Try this:

```
runOnUiThread {
    Log.e("ANAK_KOST","onDetailKontrakan")
    val destination = Intent(this@YourActivity.baseContext, YourActivity::class.java)
            .also { it.putExtra("KEY",key) } 
    startActivity(destination)
}
```

Comment: Is the activity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Sure, I've told before that startActivity with that Activity works on Another declarations. On some fragments.

Comment: Very strange. Can you share the code of the Activity(YourActivity.kt) you are trying to start?

Comment: This issue's closed by  @DanielZolnai . I do some check on the new Activity and that's make the activity closed before it's rendered. :)

Comment: Glad you found the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
val destination= Intent(baseContext,YourActivity::class.java)

Log.e("ANAK_KOST","onDetailKontrakan")

destination.putExtra("KEY",key)

baseContext.startActivity(destination)
```

In Java I use like this in Adapter :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: context variable only works on fragment, do you mean "baseContext"?

Comment: then you can use this key word

Comment: @Galihlarasprakoso please check again i have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before. In my case, caller `Activity` and destination `Activity` was the same. I mean by clicking on an item of the `RecyclerView` in `Activity` X, I tried to start X. The problem was the `launchMode` of X in manifest. I had defined it `singleTask`. So `Activity` did not started again and it felt like nothing happened when `startActivity` called.

If you have a such situation, you can try to use `onNewIntent` to know the `Activity` is started again or not.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for your contributions @aminography . :)